# HashMap<String, Set<String>> cant find its key even though it exists

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap of this type

```
Map<String, Set<String>> list_names = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
```

that I have constructed and added its elements from a txt file that has a list's name and a set of names in it.

```
98298XSD98      N9823923 N123781 N723872 ....
13214FS923      N9818324 N982389
...             ...
```

I made another HashMap, called names_list that pretty much replaces the order of the list_names HashMap such that I can get all the lists that a given name is in.

now the HashMap I have is pretty big, and there are over 400k items and 60k lists.

somewhere in my code im trying to get the Set of different lists many many times and then getting the intersection of these two lists for computational purposes,

```
a_list = this.names_lists.get(a);
b_list = this.names_lists.get(b);
// printing lists
//intersection stuff
```

but whats weird is the HashMap didn't recognizance one of its keys(or maybe many of its keys) and treated it as null after one retrieval or sometimes 0 retrievals.

```
a:0122211029:[R3DDZP35ERRSA]    b:1159829805:[R3ALX1GRMY5IMX, R1204YEYK4MBCA]
a:0122211029:[]                 b:1593072570:[R222JSDL42MS64]
```

here, im just printing the name and names_list.get(key).toString();
and yes i'm printing these before doing any intersection stuff.

any idea why is it doing that?

Comment: We need to see some minimal piece of code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate the intersection of two sets, you actually modify one of the sets. You have to create a temporary set to hold the intersection, e.g.:

```
a_list = this.names_lists.get(a);
b_list = this.names_lists.get(b);
Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<>(a_list).retainAll(b_list);
```